# Does kafka balance partitions across instances or threads?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Lets say I have a multithreaded kafkaStreams app. It's running and all the partitions were assigned so that no thread is assigned more than 1 partition.

Now the CPU on this app went way up and my autoscaler spun up another instance. Will my new instance get assigned any partitions? Or does kafka say, "I got these partitions spread out as far as I can so, thanks for the new instance, but I'm only going to use it if the existing one crashes"?

Assuming the answer is, yes kafka will not rebalance, What solutions are available to get kafka to balance across the instances

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "multithreaded kafkaStreams app" -- do you set config `num.stream.thread` to a larger value than `1` for each instance? Or do you run multiple instances?

Comment: I mean num.stream.thread. But this question involves both situations. Put it this way: If I have 2 instances with  4 threads each and 4 partitions, is there anything that will stop one instance from sucking up all the partitions?

Comment: Yes. During rebalance, Kafka Streams can distinguish the threads and knows which are from the same `KafkaStreams` instance and partitions will be assigned load balanced base on "capacity" (ie, 4 per instance in your case) to different instances.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your CPU increased because the throughput of the topic increased, not because the partitions of the topic increased.

In this case, the partitions are distributed evenly across multiple instances of the same [consumer group](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers). In general, `consumer threads * instance count <= partitions`.

If you have more total threads available than partitions, then you are oversubscribed. If you have less, then some threads will consume round-robin style from multiple partitions.

---

If the topic partitions did increase, then your threads were allocated on a more than 1:1 mapping, and consuming from several partitions. Adding additional instances rebalances the consumer group and spreads out the load.